# Android: Switch output source without interrupting music playback

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am playing music from SoundCloud with MediPlayer.
I want to be able to switch output source when I move the phone up to my ear to earpiece and back to speaker when I move away. 
Currently I have this:

```
@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) {
            if (event.values[0] == 0) {
                //near
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
                audiomgr.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "near", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                //far
                audiomgr.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "far", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

However, this does not do anything. Sensor detects that I bring the phone to and away from ear, but output source wont change.
I also need the music playback to be continuous, so that when output source changed, the music wont be interrupted.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
You need to use AudioManager for switching sound output.

```
 mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

It is important to use same mode for MediaPlayer and AudioManager.
Then you change source with:

```
mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```